What is the explanation of this hadith about black dogs?

Sunan Abu Dawud / Book 16 / Hadith 2839


حَدَّثَنَا مُسَدَّدٌ، حَدَّثَنَا يَزِيدُ، حَدَّثَنَا يُونُسُ، عَنِ الْحَسَنِ، عَنْ عَبْدِ اللَّهِ بْنِ مُغَفَّلٍ، قَالَ قَالَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم ‏
"‏ لَوْلاَ أَنَّ الْكِلاَبَ أُمَّةٌ مِنَ الأُمَمِ لأَمَرْتُ بِقَتْلِهَا فَاقْتُلُوا مِنْهَا الأَسْوَدَ الْبَهِيمَ ‏"
‏ ‏
Narrated Abdullah ibn Mughaffal:
The Prophet (ﷺ) said: Were dogs not a species of creature I should command that they all be killed; but kill every pure black one..‏
.

What is the explanation of this Hadith?
I mean, why kill black dogs for no reason?

I upvoted because this question is useful for my understanding about dogs even outside of Islam.

There are reports which give the reason:

قلت يا أبا ذر ما بال الكلب الأسود من الكلب الأحمر من الكلب الأصفر قال يا ابن أخي سألت رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم كما سألتني فقال ‏الكلب الأسود شيطان ‏
The narrator said: "O Abu Dharr, what is the difference between a black dog and a red or yellow dog?"
He said, "O son of my brother, I asked the Messenger of Allah (peace and blessings of Allah be upon him) the same question, and he said: 'The black dog is a devil.' "
— Muslim


أمرنا رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم بقتل الكلاب حتى إن المرأة تقدم من البادية بكلبها فنقتله ثم نهى النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم عن قتلها وقال عليكم بالأسود البهيم ذي النقطتين فإنه شيطان
The Messenger of Allah ﷺ ordered us to kill dogs, and even if a woman came
from the desert with her dog, we would kill it. Then the Prophet forbade killing them, and said: You should kill the dark black (dog) with two (white) spots (above its eyes), for it is a devil.
— Muslim

This could mean that it is a literal devil from the Jinn which has taken the physical form of a dog, or that it is easy for a devil to possess a black dog. Or it could mean that it is a devil in the figurative sense that it is malicious, harmful and of minimal benefit.
In terms of ruling the jurists agree that a harmful dog (black or otherwise) can be killed, some even hold that it is obligatory to kill it.

خمس فواسق يقتلن في الحل والحرم الحية والغراب الأبقع والفارة والكلب العقور والحديا
There are five vermin which may be killed inside the sanctuary and outside: Snakes, crows, mice, vicious dogs and kites.
— Muslim

As for a black dog which is not known to be harmful there is disagreement. Some hold that it is similar to any other dog and that the hadith about killing it is abrogated. Others hold that it is to be killed.
